# Questions about intersection of 2 surfaces in Manim

Tags: manim

```
class test21(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        axes = ThreeDAxes(x_range=[-6, 6], y_range=[-6, 6], z_range=[-2, 9], z_length=4)
        self.set_camera_orientation(phi=60 * DEGREES, theta=-45 * DEGREES)

        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(axes))
        func1 = Surface(lambda u, v: axes.c2p(u, v, 2 * (u * v) ** 0.5),
                        u_range=[0.001, 3],
                        v_range=[0.001, 3])

        self.play(Create(func1))
        plane=Surface(lambda u, v: axes.c2p(u, v, 2),
                                              u_range=[-3, 3],
                                              v_range=[-3, 3],checkerboard_colors=[YELLOW,GREEN])
        self.play(Create(plane))
        line=Intersection(func1,plane).set_color(RED)
        self.play(Create(line))
        self.wait()
```

Hi, when I was trying to create the intersection of 2 surfaces, I found that the output video does bot have any  intersection line. Could someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

I have tried to use the intersection function, but it didn't work.